# Reuse external R script in R Markdown

Tags: r

When using R Markdown, I would like to call an external R script to use values specified in the R Markdown file.

Ex.

`{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='hide', message=FALSE}
read_chunk('Analysis of Fulton_L_W relations_All_surveys.R')
survey <- "A"`

`{r Analysis, echo=FALSE, results='hide', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}`

Then afterwards I'd like to respecify the indput variable and rerun the script

Ex.

`{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='hide', message=FALSE}
survey <- "B"`

`{r Analysis, echo=FALSE, results='hide', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}`

However, a duplicate lable error occurs. But when I then use the options(knitr.duplicate.label = 'allow'), the second run of the analysis is not completed. I expect this is due to Knitr relabeling the chunk to Analysis-1, which is not specified in the R script.

I have also tried to run the scripts through a child-Rmd file, but this did not work either.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `source` should work for you

Consider that I have a file called `test.R`

```
x <- a + b
print(x)
```

Now, from my Rmarkdown, I will source `test.R` twice:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---


```{r}
a <- 1
b <- 2

source("test.R")
```

```{r}
a <- 3
b <- 4

source("test.R")
```
````

This gives me the result

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for.